# En que parte del IIS se configura el tiempo de duración de la sesión

Tags: genexus

¿En que parte del IIS se configura el tiempo de duración de la sesión?
Después de unos minutos me manda a pantalla de inicio de sesión del sistema, hice varias publicaciones en el IIS de la misma aplicación y dividí a los usuarios para acceder y disminuyo mucho el problema, asumo que es un buffer o algo así en el IIS o en el web.config

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del archivo web.config de la aplicación, dentro del tag system.web, debes agregar o modificar el valor de los siguientes elementos:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="numero (en segundos)"/>
    <sessionState timeout="numero (en minutos)" />
</system.web>
```

[ExecutionTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/e1f13641(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN): especifica el tiempo máximo durante el cual una solicitud puede ejecutarse antes de que ASP.NET la cierre automáticamente. Por defecto es 90 segundos.

[Timeout:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout?view=netframework-4.8.1&redirectedfrom=MSDN#System_Web_SessionState_HttpSessionState_Timeout) Especifica el número de minutos que una sesión puede estar inactiva. Por defecto es 20 minutos.